# SWIG Java - array of user defined object

Tags: java, arrays, swig, user-defined-types

In C++ I have a simple example as such

```
class z {
   public int a;
};

struct testStructure
{
   z testArray[2];
};
```

When I try to wrap it with SWIG, it is unable to return "testArray" as an array but just the object z.

I included the "arrays_java.i", but that only works for primitive types. Meaning that if in "struct testStructure" I used "int" for testArray isntead of "z", SWIG can interpret that and return an array. But for user defined types, it has troubles.

What do I have to do in the interface file such that SWIG can wrap it properly.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One option is to create some additional functions for accessing the elements of the array within your swig interface file.

```
%inline %{
    z getTestArrayElem(testStructure *ts, int index) {
        return ts->testArray[index];
    }
    void setTestArrayElem(testStructure *ts, int index, z *val) {
        ts->testArray[index] = *val;
    }
%}
```